# Drag and drop só funciona com dois cliques

Tags: javascript

Estou com problemas no "arrasta e solta" dos itens da minha lista. Eu só consigo segurar e arrastar um item depois de dar um clique único nele. Alguém sabe como eu resolvo isso ? Segue meu código:

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li>
    <a>
    <span class='item' style='cursor: pointer;' onmouseup='atualizaposicao(this.id);' id='1'>Maçã</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
    <span class='item' style='cursor: pointer;' onmouseup='atualizaposicao(this.id);' id='2'>Biribinha</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
    <span class='item' style='cursor: pointer;' onmouseup='atualizaposicao(this.id);' id='3'>Astronauta</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

```
function atualizaposicao(id) {
    var id;
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
            ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
        },
        update: function(event, ui){

            console.log("Posição inicial: " + ui.item.startPos + " Nova posição: " + ui.item.index());

            var itens = $(this).children();
            console.log("Quantidade de itens: " + itens.length);

            itens.each(function(){
                var item = $(this).children();

                var newVal = $(this).index() + 1;
                $(item).children('.index').html(newVal);

            });

            console.log("***********************************");

            var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                url: "/aleatoriedades.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    timeout: default_timeout,
                    id: id,
                    acao: "salvar_ordem",
                    novaposicao: ui.item.index(),
                    seed: random()
                }
            })
                    .done(function () {

                    })
                    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
                            swal("Tempo Esgotado", "Verifique sua conexão e tente novamente em alguns segundos.", "error")
                            return;
                        }
                        swal("Erro", "Ocorreu um erro de comunicação. Verifique sua conexão.", "error")
                    });
        }
     });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
}
```

Comment: Olá, não coloque a solução no corpo da pergunta, pode colocar como uma resposta para a sua própria pergunta entretanto ;)

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um teste rápido e me parece que seu problema é chamar a função atualizaposicao com o evento MouseUp, **você está executando toda a função quando o mouse é liberado** (varias vezes, além de não iniciar automaticamente, **sendo necessário executar um click em um item da lista antes do sortable funcionar**).

Para resolver esse problema eu alterei um pouco o código da função atualizaposicao, basicamente movi a parte do ajax para uma função **<del>change</del> stop** dentro de **sortable**.

- O evento **change** é chamada toda vez que algum item muda de posição;
- O evento **update** é chamado quando o usuário para de mover ou algum item mudou de posição;
- O evento **stop** é chamado quando o usuário para de mover (libera o item).

Para uma lista completa de eventos, [click aqui](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) (https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/).

Também modifiquei o lugar onde o ID foi definido no HTML para o **li** ao invés do **span**, apenas por ser mais fácil pegar o ID desse modo e ser mais fácil de entender/ler.

E para finalizar chame a função atualizaposicao quando a janela for carregada (adicione à tag body um `onload="atualizaposicao();"`) ou faça de outra forma.

**JS:**

```
function atualizaposicao() { //Não precisa passar o ID
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
            ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log("Posição inicial: " + ui.item.startPos + " Nova posição: " + ui.item.index());

            var itens = $(this).children();
            console.log("Quantidade de itens: " + itens.length);

            itens.each(function(){
                var item = $(this).children();

                var newVal = $(this).index() + 1;
                $(item).children('.index').html(newVal);

            });


            var id = $(ui.item).attr("id"); //Pega o ID do item que mudou de posição

            var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                url: "/aleatoriedades.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    timeout: default_timeout,
                    id: id,
                    acao: "salvar_ordem",
                    novaposicao: ui.item.index(),
                    seed: random()
                }
            }).done(function () {
                //Codigo aqui...
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                //Codigo de falha.
            }
     )}});
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
}

atualizaposicao(); //Remova essa linha se estiver chamando a função com onload.
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li  id='1'>
      <a href="#">
        <span class='item' style='cursor: pointer;'>Maçã</span>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li  id='2'>
      <a href="#">
        <span class='item' style='cursor: pointer;'>Biribinha</span>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li id='3'>
      <a href="#">
        <span class='item' style='cursor: pointer;' >Astronauta</span>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Precisa que seja no mouseup, pois quero que salve quando eu soltar o elemento. O jeito que vc sugeriu a página fica salvando todo clique que eu der no elemento. E a função não está trazendo a nova posição.

Comment: Mude change para stop (confundi os 2 quando escrevi a resposta, change é chamado quando os elementos mudam de posição, stop é chamado quando o sort é finalizado). Além disso mova o código do Update para a função do stop. Vou atualizar a resposta.